# Orchard CMS Widget Creation

Tags: content-management-system, widget, orchardcms

My goal is to create a series of widgets for Orchard I can re-use on following projects.

With that in mind I'm able to create widgets for a particular theme utilising the migrations.cs file but have found this in the orchard docs:

http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/widgets

Stating: *"A widget is composed of two or more files that are placed in a /Packages/[MyPackage]/Widgets directory of the application."* That would suit me better as in theory each widget would have it's own folder, manifest txt and be self contained with it's own resources.

My question is: Is that link out of date and therefore incorrect? And if not where would I add the 'packages' folder (I've tried adding it to various places inc the 'src' folder) but can't get it to work. Is creating a widget this way even possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working with orchard since version 1.4 and i haven't faced with this type of code to crate a widget.i think this article is out of date check this [link](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Writing-a-widget) instead to create a widget.

in a short sentence a widget is a `ContentType` which has a part called `WidgetPart`  and has `Stereotype` of `Widget`.the migration for a widget would look like this :

```
 ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("FOOWidget", cfg => cfg
                .WithPart("WidgetPart")
                .WithPart("CommonPart")
                .WithSetting("Stereotype", "Widget"));
```

hope this be useful.

Comment: Thanks Behnam. Seems a shame that particular doc is out of date, as would be nice to still create widgets that way, for ease of use and portability.

Comment: The documentation is open-source, and takes contributions. All you have to do is edit the document on Github.